# Viewing map of iSCSI target -> LU in COMSTAR

Tags: solaris, iscsi, openindiana

I'm creating a number of iSCSI targets on an OpenIndiana server using COMSTAR. Basically:

- zfs create -V 10g pool/comstar/vol
- sbdadm create-lu /dev/zvol/rdsk/pool/comstar/vol
- stmfadm add-view 600144F077000000000048C62BF00001
- itadm create-target

It's that last part I'm having a hard time understanding because I'm not telling itadm what LU to use. I assume it'll use whatever LU is available, but then after I've created a few of these, how do I know what target maps to what LU? I can't find any correlating bit of info.

'stmfadm list-lu -v' lists LU GUID and data file (e.g. /dev/zvol/rdsk/pool/comstar/vol/)
'itadm list-target -v' and 'stmfadm list-target -v' give me the target IQN but no info about what physical volume/LU they map to.

This seems like something you'd commonly want to know, but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Yeah, same q-n here )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default `add-view` will create a view with the following properties:

```
View Entry: 0
LUN          :  0
Host group   :  All
Target group :  All
```

If you want to define which targets map to a view/LU you need to create a target-group:

```
stmfadm create-tg TG1
```

then add your target to it:

```
stmfadm add-tg-member -g TG1 iqn.2010-08.org.illumos:42:4eaa957f-10d1-c40d-fadb-66b66e265e83
```

Now when you create a view, you need to tell it to use the new target group:

```
stmfadm add-view -t TG1 600144F077000000000048C62BF00001
```

The view will now look like this:

```
View Entry: 0
LUN          :  0
Host group   :  All
Target group :  TG1
    Member: iqn.2010-08.org.illumos:42:4eaa957f-10d1-c40d-fadb-66b66e265e83
        Operational Status: Online
        Provider Name     : iscsit
        Alias             : -
        Protocol          : iSCSI
        Sessions          : 0
```

Comment: I don't see how it answers the q-n. First of all, let's say we didn't create target-group as you proposed, how to get the mapping then?